# Disable CakePHP ACL/ACO checks in local dev environment

Tags: cakephp

I am attempting to disable ACL/ACO checks in my local development environment because its time consuming to sync up the ACO table everytime I create a new method or controller. I am having problems figuring out how to do this conditionally. I attempted the following code in AppController but it did not work:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    // disable ACL component in local development environments
    if(preg_match('/\.local/',FULL_BASE_URL)){
        unset($this->components['Acl']);
        unset($this->components['Auth']['authorize']);
    }
}
```

I am running CakePHP 2.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably achieve the same this way:

Add a configuration in your app/Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Auth.enabled', 0);
```

Having an explicit configuration is generally preferred over 'auto-detecting' your environment.

Then, inside your AppController;

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    if(0 === Configure::read('Auth.enabled')) {
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }
}
```

See [Making actions public](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public)

Or, to disable the component(s) altogether:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    if(0 === Configure::read('Auth.enabled')) {
        $this->Components->disable('Acl');
        $this->Components->disable('Auth');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the Components::disable method.